Magento Configurable product dropdown show text out of stock for child product M2
I would like to show a text on the dropdown on my configurable products for my child products. Now its not possible to select the product but for good sake I would like to display the text out of stockDisplay text here.
Im using M2 version 2.4.5-p1.
Is there at place where I can change / modify this?

This question may be better suited for the magento stackexchange

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have attached an image that shows what I would like to show.
